# What is the difference among information acquisition, information providing and information design?

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, game-theory, bayesian-game, information

Taking a look at the literature of information economics I see three different terminologies about information that seem to have some intersection, though my understanding is not so good. These terms refer to information acquisition, information providing and information design. Could anyone highlight the differences or similarities among these three different concepts?

Whatever example or definition could anyone provide would be appreciated.